# Setting global variable across fancebox iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancybox-2

I have a webpage and I am calling fancybox plugin iframe to show another page. I have used this page to upload an image. Now, I want to pass the image path back to the parent page after the fancybox closes.

I thought of setting a global variable on the parent page, and then set value of that variable inside the fancybox iframe (to the uploaded image path). Then on the parent page I placed the `afterClose()` for fancybox to read that variable's value. Will this work? If not, what else I can try?

Parent file code:

```
var globalImageURL = "";
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',

        afterClose: function(){
            alert(globalImageURL);
        }
    });
```

iFrame code:

```
<?php
if(strlen($photo_exists)>0){

    echo "<script>globalImageURL = 'imagepath';</script>";
}
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: where is your code dear?

Comment: why do you not try it before you ask a question? if it worked so you don't need to ask else so you can ask how to fix your problem?

Comment: @AustinNguyễn: I tried already and it didn't work. I also have the sense to try it before I ask here. And btw, this place exists to solve problem. So, tone down your attitude a bit. It will be very helpful.

Comment: Well,If you are trying to get global variable through iframe it could not be possible i think you should set the cookie for the image path and get that cookie when iframe is closed

Comment: also you can check http://stackoverflow.com/q/22737737/1055987

Comment: @Justcode: Thanks. I went the cookie way and it worked.

Comment: welcome @Blueboye i guess i could have posted it as answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the document.domain of the parent and the iframe must be same for the iframe to access parent variables.

Secondly the code should look like this:-

```
<?php
if(strlen($photo_exists)>0){

    echo "<script>if(top.globalImageURL) top.globalImaeUIrl='imagepath';</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Tried but didn't work :(

Comment: Also check that return function in fancy box to have a top.globalImageURL in alert rather than globalImageURL  to prevent js error on page.